# Saving the SSRS report Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have SSRS report which takes multiple parameters to run each time. When ever the user wants to run the report he always need to fill in those parameters. Do we have solution within in SSRS services to save those parameters as template and use them for future run OR what is the best way to achieve this to save the report parameters as template.

Currently I have the SSRS report, which is viewed in Sharepoint

Comment: Google 'default parameter in ssrs' - first hit tells you how.

Answer (score 1):

This is a theory that I haven't tested, and so not sure how efficient it will be.  But the idea goes like this

Although you don't save the last used parameters, you could possibly look at the last time the report was run by the user in the `ExecutionLog` table extract the parameters that were supplied to this report and use that as default for the next run.

A simply query of the execution log will give you the details :

```
SELECT 
R.Name
,L.[Parameters]
,L.username
,L.TimeStart 

FROM dbo.ExecutionLog L WITH (NOLOCK)  

INNER JOIN dbo.Catalog R WITH (NOLOCK) 
    ON L.ReportID = R.ItemID 

WHERE R.Name =  'your report name'
and L.username = @user_name
```

This will give you the history (depending on your RS setting) of the report.

Just use the latest instance of the log (max L.TimeStart perhaps). Then extract the parameters and then set the default value of the report..

Once again.. not sure how efficient this is, but it **could** possibly work!

If your parameters are cascading parameters, then you could hit trouble as the previous parameter value may not be valid any more.. But you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save a previous choice made in SSRS by an individual user so  that the choice will appear the next time that user signs in. You can have a default choice by setting up a default value. This default value will appear for every user of the report every time the report is run. You can make that the default value be the result of a  select but whatever logic you build into the default value that  logic will  be applied every time the report is run.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN do this....

Let's say we had two parameters , @Country and @Category that are used in the report.

Typically the available values would be from a dataset that looks something like this,

```
SELECT DISTINCT CountryID, CountryName FROM myTable ORDER BY CountryName
```

...and similar for categories

So let's say the user runs the report with parameters as follows

CountryID = 89, 94, 245 (France, Germany and UK)
and 
CategoryID = 11, 15 (Cars, Bikes)

We need to create a table to store these values along with the user.
Something like

```
CREATE TABLE userParams(userName nvarchar(128), reportName nvarchar(128), paramName nvarchar(128), paramValue int)
```

Them at the start of your dataset query for the main report you can save the parameter values...

```
DELETE FROM userParams WHERE userName = SYSTEM_USER AND reportName = 'myReportName'
INSERT INTO userParams
    SELECT DISTINCT SYSTEM_USER, 'myReportname', 'Country', CountryID FROM myTable WHERE CountryID IN (@Country)
INSERT INTO userParams
    SELECT DISTINCT SYSTEM_USER, 'myReportname', 'Category', CategoryID FROM myTable WHERE CategoryID IN (@Category)
```

OK, so now we have the last parameters saved per user, we just need to create a dataset to read them in and use them as the default values.

Create a dataset called `dsCountry_Defaults` with a dataset query something like...

```
SELECT CountryID from userParams WHERE userName = SYSTEM_USER and reportName = 'myReportName'
```

In your Country paramater settings set the default parameters to a query and point to this dataset.

Repeat this for the remaining parameter.

That should be it...

If you are using SP's as your dataset then you will need to modify this slightly but the principle is the same.